# How do I get the latest content of a .deb file without downloading redundant data?

Tags: apt, software-recommendation

I want to update a .deb file with the latest content from available update. I searched and found `apt-sync` program, however, this [apt-sync](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/apt-sync) project seems dead.

Is there any alternative of it? or Is this moved to somewhere else? or How can I achieve the same result?

Comment: Here is another discussion https://wiki.ubuntu.com/APTPackageDeltas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently I am following this procedure.

1. Log into my [Koding](http://koding.com) cloud space.
2. Fire-up a terminal there and download the package's deb file using `apt-get download`.
3. Extract the downloaded .deb file using `dpkg-deb -R <deb-file> .` to get the content of the file.
4. Move the contents to a suitable directory. For example, `/home/anwarshah/contents`
5. In local pc, Extract the old deb's content in a directory, preferably in a directory with same remote name i.e `contents`.
6. Use `rsync` to synchronize the contents

   ```
   rsync -a -i -h -v -c <myusername@myusername>.koding.io:/home/<myusername>/contents/ /home/anwar/contents/
   ```
7. Now build the newly synched package using `dpkg-deb`

   ```
   dpkg-deb --build /home/anwar/contents
   ```
8. A new .deb file will be created with name `contents.deb`. Rename this to standard package format using `dpkg-name`

   ```
   dpkg-name contents.deb
   ```
9. Now I have the .deb file with latest contents without having to download extra redundant data. It was very helpful for large packages with multimedia data such as `kde-wallpapers` etc.

#### Alternative way

1. Find a cloud VM where you can download the .deb files.
2. Use `zsyncmake` to create a .deb.zsync file
3. Use `zsync` to download .deb file after making the file available to be downloaded. Make sure to read the [zsync manual](http://man.cx/zsync%281%29).

Zsync is a program similar to rsync, which aims to reduce the data needed for download for compressed files. It basically updates a large compressed file with the latest content of that compressed file from Internet. Ubuntu provides .iso.zsync for it's ISOs which is efficient to save some (around 35%) bandwidth, if you already have the ISO locally.